In a ggplot, I want to connect points within my x grouping variables with a line
I have a grouping variable called Pathway2 and a further grouping Treatment variable.
I want the two levels of the Treatment variable to be connected by a line according to my grouping variables.
My code currently is this, which produces the following figure.
ggplot(df, aes(x = Pathway2, y = Detected.spots, color = Treatment)) +
    geom_point(size = 3, stat = 'summary', fun.y = 'mean', position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
    geom_errorbar(stat = 'summary', fun.data = 'mean_se', width = 0, fun.args = list(mult = 1.96), 
                  position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
    geom_line(stat = 'summary', aes(group = Treatment), position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +  # Összekapcsolt vonalak hozzáadása
    facet_wrap(~Cancer.type.in.co.culture + Time, ncol = 2) +
    labs(x = "Pathway", y = "Detected spot", color = "Treatment") +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red")) +
    theme_gray(base_size = 20)


But I would like to see this result, can anyone help me?


Change the group aesthetic to be mapped to the pathway variable.  So geom_line(aes(group=Pathway2), col="black")

Hi George! Thanks.
Yes, I've been through these rounds. Unfortunately they don't connect them, the lines just disappear. I've just corrected the post and added the script had forgotten before.

thanks for adding the code. So you're making summaries within ggplot and you need group already for creating the summaries. I'm not sure if this is possible, you may need to calculate a summary dataset before passing to ggplot.  Also think about whether the dodge and lines are needed for this graph!

The difficulty is dodging one end of the line one way and the other end another :)
There are a couple of options (and may be others):

The first is easier by having a combined Pathway & Treatment on the x-axis.
The second is aesthetically nicer, but a little trickier as it's a two-step plot to first get the plotting coordinates of the dodged points, then calculate where to put the lines.

See if either of these work for you?
(There's also ggpaired() in ggpubr that might be worth looking at, but might need reshaped data.)
I've made up a small amount of sample data as we don't have yours, but hopefully it's enough to illustrate the options.
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~Pathway2, ~Detected.spots, ~Treatment, ~Cancer.type.in.co.culture, ~Time,
  "C-E", 1, "a", "Melanona", 24,
  "C-E", 2, "a", "Melanona", 24,
  "C-E", 5, "b", "Melanona", 24,
  "C-E", 6, "b", "Melanona", 24,
  "C-F", 1, "a", "Melanona", 24,
  "C-F", 2, "a", "Melanona", 24,
  "C-F", 6, "b", "Melanona", 24,
  "C-F", 7, "b", "Melanona", 24
)

# Option 1 - x-axis is Pathway & Treatment instead of dodging
df |> 
  mutate(pairing = paste(Pathway2, "\n", Treatment)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = pairing, y = Detected.spots, color = Treatment)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, stat = 'summary') +
  geom_errorbar(stat = 'summary', fun.data = 'mean_se', width = 0, fun.args = list(mult = 1.96)) +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', aes(group = Pathway2), colour = "grey30", linetype = "dashed") + 
  facet_wrap(~Cancer.type.in.co.culture + Time, ncol = 2) +
  labs(x = "Pathway", y = "Detected spot", color = "Treatment") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red")) +
  theme_gray(base_size = 20)



# Option 2 - Save the plot without lines, get the coordinates of the points, then add lines
p <- df |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = Pathway2, y = Detected.spots, color = Treatment)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, stat = 'summary', position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_errorbar(stat = 'summary', fun.data = 'mean_se', width = 0, fun.args = list(mult = 1.96), 
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  # geom_line(stat = 'summary', aes(group = Treatment), position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Cancer.type.in.co.culture + Time, ncol = 2) +
  labs(x = "Pathway", y = "Detected spot", color = "Treatment") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red")) +
  theme_gray(base_size = 20)

line_df <- layer_data(p, 1) |> 
  select(x, y, Treatment = colour) |> 
  mutate(pairing = (row_number() + 1) %/% 2)

p + geom_line(aes(x, y, group = pairing), colour = "grey30", data = line_df)


Created on 2024-04-25 with reprex v2.1.0
